# Why isn't my bootstrap 'col-sm-12' working for mobile design?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with the Bootstrap mobile design. Even though I type col-sm-12 it doesn't resize exactly in mobile design. how can i solve this problem? I am using bootstrap 5.3.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0-alpha3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-iGjGmwIm1UHNaSuwiNFfB3+HpzT/YLJMiYPKzlQEVpT6FWi5rfpbyrBuTPseScOCWBkRtsrRIbrTzJpQ02IaLA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mx-auto">
      <div class="card mt-5">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="card-text">
            <span>Giriş</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-body">
          <form method="POST" action="">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label class="form-label" for="kullaniciAdi">Kullanıcı Adı:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="kullaniciAdi" placeholder="Lütfen kullanıcı adınızı giriniz." required>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label class="form-label" for="sifre">Şifre:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Lütfen şifrenizi giriniz." required>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Giriş Yap</button>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button" type="button" href="Kayit">Kayıt Ol</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. Also, consider not using an alpha version of any library. Use the stable version (5.2) instead.

Comment: The snippet you've shown here doesn't behave as what's in your image. Please update the demo so it does.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that's because the `sm` [breakpoint](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/breakpoints/) is larger than your viewport width. Try just using `col-12`, which is the default (`xs`) set.

`xs` (none): < 576px

`sm`: >= 576px

`md`: >= 768px

`lg`: >= 992px

`xl`: >= 1200px

`xxl`: >= 1400px

Comment: didn't work, size didn't change on mobile.
As mentioned above, I updated the bootstrap to stable version (5.2).

Comment: Have you looked at it on an actual phone? Sometimes emulators can behave strangely.

Comment: yes i checked from real phone the situation is the same

Comment: It's behaving as expected in the snippet you added. Is it possible some other styling is adding a padding or margin that's forcing the col to be smaller?

Comment: yes as you said another css file is triggering this problem solved thanks.